# How to add new page to PrintPreviewControl and separate rows in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, print-preview

I have 2 Forms:

Form1: is my DataGridView with 48 Items/Rows

Form2: is my PrintPreviewControl with "Dock: Fill"

Now I need help to separate the Rows in `DataGridView` and add for example in Page1 in my Form2, 24 Rows from the DGV and in Page2 the rest 24 Rows.

I don't know how to separate rows and import in 2 pages.

When I import the rows the way they are.. the rows go down the page and doesn't create a new page (but still even with the new page, don't know how to separate the half rows or specific value I choose into 2 pages)

Form1: Button1: `Form2.show()`

Form2:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

Dim x As Integer = 170
Dim y As Integer = 360
Dim xwidth As Integer = 190
Dim yheight As Integer = 20

Dim fon As New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
Dim rect As New Rectangle(x, 100, xwidth, yheight)

Dim rek1 As New Rectangle(40, 370, 750, 380)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rek1)

Dim row = Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
e.Graphics.DrawString(Form1.DataGridView1.Item(Form1.Column1.Name, row).Value.ToString, fon, Brushes.Black, 60, 380)
e.Graphics.DrawString(Form1.DataGridView1.Item(Form1.Column2.Name, row).Value.ToString, fon, Brushes.Black, 200, 380)
e.Graphics.DrawString(Form1.DataGridView1.Item(Form1.Column3.Name, row).Value.ToString, fon, Brushes.Black, 400, 380)

End Sub
```

Comment: Format code using ```, and fix grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might print 24 records to a page from a `DataGridView`:

```
Private Const RECORDS_PER_PAGE As Integer = 24

Private lastRecordIndex As Integer

Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    'Reset the record index.
    lastRecordIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'Start printing at the next record or, if no records have been printed, the first record.
    Dim firstRecordIndex = lastRecordIndex + 1

    'The data entry row is not to be printed.
    Dim printableRowCount = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    'Print a page of data or the rest of the data, whichever is smaller.
    lastRecordIndex = Math.Min(lastRecordIndex + RECORDS_PER_PAGE, printableRowCount - 1)

    For i = firstRecordIndex To lastRecordIndex
        Dim row = DataGridView1.Rows(i)

        'Print row as appropriate.
    Next

    'Print another page if and only if there is more data.
    e.HasMorePages = (lastRecordIndex < printableRowCount - 1)
End Sub
```

The `BeginPrint` event allows you to initialise any state that relates to the entire print run.  The `PrintPage` event allows you to print one page of data.  It's up to you to track what page you're up to.  The `e.HasMorePages` property indicates whether there are more pages to print, i.e. whether the `PrintPage` event will be raised again.